# Web capability with flutter package: mapbox_gl

Tags: flutter, mapbox-gl

The mapbox gl package page lists it as suitable for web applications ([mapbox_gl](https://pub.dev/packages/mapbox_gl)).
I tried running the example as a web application, but I encounter the error `Error creating mapbox_gl_example|lib/move_camera.ddc.dill
Error creating kernel summary for module:mapbox_gl_example|lib/move_camera.ddc.dill`
.

So, my question is, is the flutter package `mapbox_gl` actually able to be run as a web application as the tags "`FLUTTER ANDROID IOS WEB`" suggest (is there something I must configure), or is it really not web capable as may be indicated by the fact that the actual description mentions nothing of web capability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** The mapbox_gl flutter plugin now has web support merged into master on Github. If you don't want to wait until web support is released to pub.dev, you can depend on the Github repo directly with this dependency in pubspec.yaml:

```
mapbox_gl:
  git:
    url: git://github.com/tobrun/flutter-mapbox-gl.git
```

**Outdated answer:** Unfortunately, it doesn't support web yet (although PRs are welcome if you want to contribute). The reason it was listed as supporting web (like many other plugins) was that flutter changed the way plugins declare their supported platforms in the pubspec.yaml file. The mapbox_gl package has since been updated on pub.dev and now correctly shows that it only supports Android and iOS.